# How to ensure programmatically selected text is visible in Quill when scrollbars present

Tags: javascript, quill

I have Quill inside a fixed-height div so that I can display Quill along other divs/panels on the page. Thus the Quill div has scrollbars once the text gets long enough.

In response to some user actions in the other panels, I use `Quill.prototype.setSelection` (http://quilljs.com/docs/api/#quillprototypesetselection) which works great when the overall text is short enough that the whole document is visible. But how can I make sure that for longer documents I also scroll to the relevant portion of the doc so that the selection is visible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `quill.getBounds()` to retrieve the bounds of the selection area and set the scroll height. Ex.

```
quill.setSelection(10, 20);
var bounds = quill.getBounds(10, 20);
quill.container.scrollTop = bounds.top;
```